# clear floating when 3 div box inside main-div wrap

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have my main div id `#main` which contains 3 div class `.left` `.right` and `.left-top`. 
left and left-top div box are floated to left, while right box to right. Css and Html are given below.Here I don't know why my right box is floating downward equal to height of `left-top` box and placing like having some top-margin to it.I want this `right` div at the extreme top only.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9zTXt/2/

```
HTML:

<div id = "main">
<div class= "left-top"></div>
<div class = "left"></div>
<div class = "right"></div>    
</div>


CSS:

#main
{position:relative;
width:350px;height:800px;
background:grey; 
margin-top:20px;     
}
#main .left
{float:left;
position:relative;width:200px;height:800px;
background:red;
margin-top:10px;
}
#main .left-top 
{width:200px;height:30px;
background:blue;
}

#main .right
{float:right;position:relative;
width:130px;height:800px;background:green;
margin:10px 0px 0px 20px;   
}
```

Comment: your css doesn't match your jsfiddle? is it this what you're talking about http://jsfiddle.net/9zTXt/2/ ?

Comment: yes i have updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/9zTXt/4/

html

```
<div id = "main">
    <div>
        <div class= "left-top"></div>
        <div class = "left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "right"></div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
#main .right
{
    float:right;position:relative;
    width:130px;height:800px;background:green;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;   
}

#main > div {
  float: left;
}
```

**explanation:** basically wrap your left floating elements on their own div so that they don't mess with the right floating element, and take out the margin-top from your `.right` div

Comment: Yes this is what I want , The main solution is wrapping left float in its own div so its separates and element within it never collide with outside divs.

Comment: If still .right is wrapped by #main ,and if #main float:left don't mess my other styling inside #divs then its ok

Comment: yup that is correct.. `.right` is still wrapped by `#main`.. and as long as `#main` has 0 margin and padding, applying a `float:left` to main won't have any effect on the divs contained within it.. i encourage you to test that by copying and pasting my code into a stand alone browse (ie not just jsfiddle) and seeing it for yourself.. if it works.. I hope to get the correct answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Try to reorder your divs so that the `div.right` comes first.

Answer (score 0):

My new sequence is

```
<div id="main">

<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top-left"></div>

</div>
```

with top-margin:30px for left div and 0px for right div.

Comment: With floating left you cannot have the top div after the left div. Please see my answer: The order should be right, top-left, left. The Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zTXt/3/

Comment: yess its nice! but can i have same view with left come first, Actually  LEFT is my main content box RIGHT is my sidebar and TOP-LEFT is the banner-bar in my layout. I had never seen sidebar written first before content box in layout.